# Is there a native C++ version of XMLConvert in .Net?

Tags: c++, xml

I am adding the ability to save as XML to several native C++ classes. I am looking for something in C++ that performs the same  job as XmlConvert from .Net.

```
double d = 45.5454545;
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeAtring(XmlConvert.ToString(d));
```

Comment: I usually use http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/ when dealing with simple xml in C++. Easy to add to a project and easy do use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [boost XML serilization](http://programmers-blog.com/2008/06/22/very-simple-c-boost-xml-serialization-example).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Test {
private:    
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar,
            const unsigned int version) {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(c);
    }

    int a;
    int b;
    float c;
public:
    inline Test(int a, int b, float c) {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
        this->c = c;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::ofstream ofs("filename.xml");

    Test* t = new Test(1, 2, 3.3);

    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(t);

    return 0;
}
```

If using boost is out of question you can simply borrow the idea provided your objects are very simple and don't have references to each other.

1. Create a **XMLDocument**
2. Each of your class has a **Serialize(XMLDocument*)** method
3. In their Serialize method they update XMLDocument with the members.

Unfortunately C++ doesn't have reflection is it impossible to do serialization easily without handling each class.

Comment: Unfortunately there are not plans to add boost to the code base. STL is all they use.

Comment: @Soppus: This is the sort of things that are important to point out to management: at this point we can unroll our own version or use boost, the advantages of boost are ... (stable, well documented, a single `serialize` can be used to serialize to different formats...), while our solution will require more time, probably have bugs and usually not be so generic... unless we mimic the boost library, in which case it will be too expensive to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use [simple XMLparser](http://www.applied-mathematics.net/tools/xmlParser.html). It is one header and one source, written in c++, and is far more efficient than anything else. It is simple and easy to use.

You only have to work with one class, XMLNode, which does all the job.

Comment: Looks interesting, will give it to the Architect for a look.
Thanks